# "UTC" is recognized as "Z" to be compatible with the legacy style

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I transfer data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL using Embulk. Postgresql version 15.4

Below are the drivers I used and the input and output gems installed in the embulk gem list.

```
Java version: 1.8
SQL : sqljdbc42.jar
PostgreSQL: postgresql-42.7.0.jar

Gems list;
embulk-input-sqlserver (0.13.2 java)
embulk-output-postgresql (0.8.7)
```

This is the error I get while transferring, can you support me?

```
2023-12-04 18:49:04.164 +0300 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-sqlserver (0.13.2)
2023-12-04 18:49:04.221 +0300 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-postgresql (0.8.7)
2023-12-04 18:49:04.338 +0300 [WARN] (0001:transaction): "UTC" is recognized as "Z" to be compatible with the legacy style.
```

Then getting error like that;

```
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.embulk.spi.time.Timestamp.ofInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;)Lorg/embulk/spi/time/Timestamp;
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:375)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:607)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:391)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:387)
    at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:25)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:387)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:180)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:331)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:174)
    at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:468)
    at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:100)
    at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.embulk.spi.time.Timestamp.ofInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;)Lorg/embulk/spi/time/Timestamp;
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.getRepresentativeException(BulkLoader.java:315)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.execute(BulkLoader.java:732)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$300(BulkLoader.java:35)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4$1$1$1.run(BulkLoader.java:568)
    at org.embulk.output.jdbc.AbstractJdbcOutputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcOutputPlugin.java:423)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4$1$1.transaction(BulkLoader.java:560)
    at org.embulk.exec.LocalExecutorPlugin.transaction(LocalExecutorPlugin.java:54)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4$1.run(BulkLoader.java:555)
    at org.embulk.spi.util.Filters$RecursiveControl.transaction(Filters.java:96)
    at org.embulk.spi.util.Filters.transaction(Filters.java:49)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$4.run(BulkLoader.java:549)
    at org.embulk.input.jdbc.AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.transaction(AbstractJdbcInputPlugin.java:230)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:544)
```

I tried changing the drivers, I changed the versions in the gem list.

Comment: Dates in databases have no format, they're binary values. There's no `Z` or `UTC`. That said, there *are* differences from one product to another. SQL Server's `datetimeoffset` type stores the offset along with the datetime, while PostgreSQL's `timestamp with timezone` converts the time UTC and discards the original offset. If EmBulk tries to convert `datetimeoffset` values to strings, it has a major bug. Or at least it requires you to somehow change that string to UTC

Comment: 1) Did the data, in particular the timestamps, transfer?  2) This `[WARN] (0001:transaction): "UTC" is recognized as "Z" to be compatible with the legacy style.` is just a warning, a heads ups if you will, that the driver made a decision about how to interpret `UTC`.

Comment: Sounds like the lib you're using have some bugs, since its code in on the stacktrace. Might wanna report that. Although, sqljdbc42.jar sounds kinda old, there are drivers at 11 version nowadays

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the comment was about the SQL Server driver. And the Github source shows that EmBulk *does* convert `datetimeoffset` to a string instead of an OffsetDateTime instance.

Comment: I transferred the data via ODI. Date fields in Postgresql are timestamp +3 UTC. I think the problem is with the drivers, but I am not sure if there is a need for any casting or conversion process when fetching date fields from SQL and transmitting them to Postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Embulk 0.8.38 and are asking about the following error

```
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.embulk.spi.time.Timestamp.ofInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;)Lorg/embulk/spi/time/Timestamp;`
```

I suspect you are using too old of an Embulk version. Could you try the [0.9.25](https://github.com/embulk/embulk/releases/tag/v0.9.25) or the [0.11.2](https://github.com/embulk/embulk/releases/tag/v0.11.2) release?

***Note:*** When you use 0.11.2, you need to follow [a few additional steps](https://www.embulk.org/articles/2023/04/13/embulk-v0.11-is-coming-soon.html) (e.g., setup JRuby).